# CSS content not working for some cases

Tags: css

I am trying to incorporate CSS before content.
I want to put  info icon (i), which is "\e608"

```
#securityCodeLink:before {
    content: "\e608";
}
```

The output looks like this

[image: e608]

But if i try with 2701 or something like that

```
#securityCodeLink:before {
    content: "\2701";
}
```

It works perfectly fine.

[image: 2701]

Can any one tell me why is this and how can i fix this?

Comment: Did you add the font-family?

Comment: Yes i have font family.

Comment: font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

Comment: so Helvetica New dosent have this symbol right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon will only appear if you're using a font which supports it.

On StackOverflow (which uses a `font-family` of `Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans'`):

`\e608` renders as 

`\2701` renders as ઍ

Answer (score 0):

I researched a lot about this and finally it get Solved..

The icon will only appear if you're using Specific Font which supports it.
In CSS we need to define the font as below.

```
@font-face{
font-famiy:'nameOfFont';
src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64______format("woff");
}

.requiredFont input[type=radio]{
    font-family: nameOfFont;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
 .requiredFont input[type=radio]{
    content: "\E608";
}

.requiredFont input[type=radio]:checked {
    content: "\E609";
    color: reqired HEX Color;
}
```

Most Probably It will work...when we design the font for the content in radio button we want..